# Finding end of vid time

Tags: xcode, video, transition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9oYm.png)So I have this code written up. and it automatically plays the video on launch of app (like I want it to), but id like to find out how to find the end of the vid so I can continue. As of now, once vid is done, it just stays on vid. im trying to get it to transition, so I can add on to my main screen once vid is finished. was told I need to find end of vid to do this, but the help I was given was outdated and didn't work.

I tried googling it and even already asked questions on stack flow, but for what im trying to do seems like no one has done it but im sure someone has or at least knows how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Click on "enter image description here" it'll take u to the screenshot of my code